# Cosmos DB - partial match of objects using IDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

We are using Azure Cosmos DB and use the microsoft.azure.documentdb.core nuGet package to send queries to it.
This works well for most of our queries, but we now have a query that we have trouble to translate.

Assume this simple type of object:

```
{ type: "abc",
  flags: [
     { feature: "x", scope: "user", value: "on" },
     { feature: "y", scope: "global", value: "off" }
  ]
}
```

Now lets say we want to get all these objects matching some feature and scope, but completely ignoring the value.

This could be done using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyCollection c WHERE /*other filters*/ and ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.flags, { feature: 'x', scope: 'user' }, true)
```

When I try to map this to C# I get this:

```
public class Flag {
   public string feature { get; set; }
   public string scope { get; set; }
   public string value { get; set; }
}

public class MyRecRepo {
   public async ICollection<MyRecType> GetRecordsWithFlag(Flag: flag) {

      var request = client
         .CreateDocumentQuery(collection, feedoptions)
         .Where(rec => /*other filters*/ && rec.flags.Contains(flagFilter));

      return await request
         .AsDocumentQuery()
         .ExecuteNextAsync<MyRecTyp>();
   }
}

//called like this:
var flagFilter = new Flag { feature = "x", scope = "user" };
var list = await repo.GetRecordsWithFlag(flagFilter);
```

PS: I want to use the same code to get any combination of flag filters.
So filter on flags that have only "feature: x", or records that have feature "y" and value "on" ...
So I think I could create one class per combination of properties, but that seems like it's to much work certainly if the real live code actually has more properties.

*PS: I know that the example code will not compile, it is pseudo code to make it a bit more readable.*

Answer (score 0):

ARRAY_CONTAINS with partial matches isn't supported via Linq queries. You have two options to work around this, but they are both a bit messy.

1. Build the SQL query yourself. You can make use of reflection to go through the properties in your Flag object and only use the ones that are set.
2. Use Any(). Instead of `SELECT r FROM r WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.property1, “{‘name1’: ‘value1’}”, true)`, Any()
   evaluates to `SELECT r FROM r WHERE EXISTS(SELECT p FROM p IN r.property1 WHERE p.name1 = ‘value1’)`.

   At this point you still need to overcome the issue of only looking
   at specific properties. You can change this by passing in your
   expression directly instead of an object. The method becomes
   `GetRecordsWithFlag(Expression<Func<MyRecType, bool>> expression)`
   and the call `repo.GetRecordsWithFlag(d => /*{other filters} */ && d.flags.Any(f => f.feature == "y" && f.value == "on"))'`

   Where this method gets messy is that you'll notice that I had to
   include all the filters in the method call. You can use
   `Expression.AndAlso()` to combine your flag filters with ones you
   are currently setting in your repo method, but there is an issue with
   nested filters in WHERE clauses that makes this result in an invalid query. [The team is
   aware](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1184) of this, but it's in one of the dependencies, so it's not
   easy to solve.